# Spring OAuth dynamically choose authentication provider based on the client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth, spring-oauth2

I already could add multiple authentication providers as mentioned in [Adding multiple authenticaion providers](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-auth-providers). Now Spring will check in both LDAP and database for users.

However my use case is little different. I want to bind a authentication provider per a client, not check in all providers. Say for clients with clienti_d1 and client_id2 it will check users in LDAP and for client_id3 it will check database. Basically LDAP based authentication for internal apps and database based authentication for external apps.

```
POST /oauth/token for client_id1:secret1 => hit LDAP authentication
POST /oauth/token for client_id2:secret2 => hit DB authentication
```

Comment: Did you resolve your issue ?

Comment: @user3529850 yes, but in a different way. I created a custom grant type that check users in DB. Then client_id2 generates token using that grant type so users will be searched in DB. client_id1 generated token using password grant type so users will be searched in LDAP.

Comment: I have similar issue, can you please share the code ?